# Ошибка в открытии файла

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram, бот

Для телеграмма отправляю фото с подписью и возникла ошибка при отправлении файла который расположен на стороннем ресурсе

```
await bot.send_photo( message.chat.id, 
                      types.InputFile( f"https://via.placeholder.com/600x150.png",
                      'rb'))
```

выдает ошибку

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x150.png'
```

Где ошибка?

Есть предположение что этот файл надо скачать

Answer (score 1):

отправка по урл:

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo='https://via.placeholder.com/600x150.png')
```

отправка с локального диска

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('path/to/file/image.png', 'rb'))
```

читаем [документацию](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#working-with-files-and-media)

Comment: Не совсем подходит такой вариант. Так как к такой реализации невозможно добавить описание.

Comment: send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo='https://via.placeholder.com/600x150.png', caption='blabla')

Comment: Спасибо огромное!